# Which is the best searching technique for file search in android mobile?

Tags: android, search, file-search

Can any body tell me which is the best searching technique for searching files on android mobile.? 
I hv used sequential searching technique. Is there any algorithm which is more efficient than sequential/linear.
If any pleas tell me how is it efficient?

Pleas help me out.

Comment: Go for Binary search.

Comment: thank you shree202. But is there any other than standard one like linear/sequential or binary.?